# Algorithm for finding circular mappings of maximal size

Tags: algorithm

I have nine sets of 500 objects each. Although the sets are independent, I assume that the sets share a core of common objects. However, one and the same object may have a different name (index) depending on the set. But I can measure the pairwise distance between two objects.

Based on the pairwise distances, I already computed optimal mappings between objects of two sets for all pairs of sets. So, for every pair of sets, I can say the correspondence between any two objects.

Now I want to detect closed mapping circles, e.g. { 5 (set 1) -> 13 (set 2) -> 24 (set 3) -> 5 (set 1) }, i.e. object 5 of set 1 maps to object 13 of set 2, which maps to 24 in set 3, which then maps back to object 5 of set 1. I need this form of a circular mapping to argue that the objects are essentially the same.

Of course, in an ideal world, I could identify a majority of circles that span all nine sets. However, common objects between 3-9 sets are also interesting. Thus, I want an exhaustive listing.

Do you know an algorithm to perform this task, or how this problem is termed in combinatorial mathematics!?

As a heuristic approach, I would start by determining circles within all combinations of 3 sets and then combine these results for larger combinations of sets.

Comment: Not sure I am following, are you looking for a cycle that includes most objects, while "jumping" between sets? It smells a lot like [Hamiltonian Path Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem) I am afraid :|

Comment: I can't really follow the problem description, but it sounds like you are looking for isomorphisms between the sets?

Comment: Is there a specific point of my explanations, which is hard to follow? maybe I could clarify...

Comment: Well, I have optimal mappings between objects of any pair of sets. Now I want to generalize these mappings to find mappings between 3-9 sets. So, I have isomorphisms for every pair of sets, but now I want to extend them to all subsets of size 3-9 of the 9 nine sets.

Comment: Essentially, what I am looking for seems to be the maximum clique problem.

Comment: Can one object be mapped to multiple objects of a target set? (is the mapping a function or a relation?)

Comment: Maximum clique is a different (but better) criterion for what I think you're trying to do.  It is NP-hard, unfortunately, but since the maximum clique size is 9 it should be fast in practice.

Comment: @Asiri: Between any two sets I have an unambiguous mapping of objects. So one object only maps one object of the other set and vice versa.

Comment: Hi there,I want to use this Java implementation: http://jgrapht.org/javadoc/org/jgrapht/alg/BronKerboschCliqueFinder.html But there it says "graph - the graph in which cliques are to be found; graph must be simple". Does anyone can explain what 'simple' means!?

Comment: @user1881788 just a conjecture, but they might be asking for graphs involving less than a certain number of vertices/edges; considering the problem is NP-hard, but as j_random_hacker notes, that isn't a problem in your case. (Personally, I would just decompile and check, but others might have morals :P)

Comment: @user1881788 The formal definition of a simple graph is a graph with no more than one edge between any two vertices, but the documentation might refer to Filipq's definition.

Comment: You didn't say what the objects are, yet want us to give a mapping to prove that they are the same as one another. Couldn't this be formulated more clearly?

Answer (score 0):

If I follow your description correctly, it seems you'll like to find correspondences between the sets. Will this algorithm work for you.

```
 1. Intialize a hashmap H
 2. Initialize key frequency map U = {}
 3. for each set i 
 4.    for each element e in set i
 5.        H.insert {e.key, {i, ...}}
 6.        if U.contain(e.key)
 7.            c = U.get(e.key)
 8.           U.update(e.key,  c + 1)
 9.        else
10.            U.insert(e.key,  1)
11.        endif 
12.    endfor
13. endfor
```

Line 5 will insert an element into the map H. Elements with the same key are stored in a linked list. You can find the longest chain by finding the the key with the largest frequency in U. Then by doing H.get(key), you'll get back the list. By linking the last element to the first, you'll obtain the cycle you seek.

I hope this helps.